# Delphi default param for TArray<string> not supported in Berlin?

Tags: delphi, generics, delphi-10.1-berlin, delphi-10.2-tokyo

I have the following definition for a method in Delphi 10.2 Tokyo, which works fine:

```
procedure PopulateParameters(
    lUrlParams: TStrings; 
    const Username: string; 
    const Password: string; 
    StartDate: TDateTime = cUnassignedDate; 
    EndDate: TDateTime = cUnassignedDate; 
    LastDate : TDateTime = cUnassignedDate; 
    Frequency : integer = 0; 
    ArrayParam : string = ''; 
    ArrayData : TArray<string> = []; 
    ArraySeparator : char = ',');
```

However,  I also have to support 10.1 Berlin, and I'm finding it is complaining about the `ArrayData` default value of `[]`.

Is this a known problem, and if so is there a workaround?

Comment: Have you tried using `nil` instead of `[]`? `TArray<T>` is an alias for a dynamic `array of T`, which is just a pointer under the hood. `ArrayData : TArray<string> = nil;`

Comment: Thanks Remy,  that worked - didn't even think of using nil.

Comment: As I expected, the error is `E2010 Incompatible types: 'System.TArray<System.string>' and 'Set'`. Well, that make perfect sense: `[]` is the empty set. Also, you can't define **compound parameters** (arrays, records) the same way you can define constants. You can't define a record or static array that way either. The alternative are open array parameters, but that has some other disadvantages.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis, we should note, that the above code works perfectly since 10.2 Tokyo, where `[]` is either the empty set or the empty array.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis Actually the error does not make sense and is in fact a bug fixed in 10.2 because depending on the lhs the compiler can determine very well if its an empty set or an empty array.